# Proving $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}} = 1+\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

How would I show $\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}} = 1+\sqrt{3}$?

I tried starting from the LHS, and rationalising and what-not but I can't get the result...
Also curious to how they got the LHS expression from considering the right.

Comment: Quite obviously, you start from the _RHS_.

Comment: I thought it would be much easier to start from a more complicated expression and simplifying it

Comment: You thought wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Squaring both sides, you get$$3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}=4+2\sqrt3,$$which is equivalent to $\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}=1+2\sqrt3$. Squaring again both sides, you get $13+4\sqrt3=13+4\sqrt3$, and we're done.

Note that you can square at will, since we are dealing only with numbers greater than or equal to $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$ \sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt3}}= \sqrt{3+\sqrt{1+2\times2\sqrt{3}+(2\sqrt{3})^2}}$$ 
$$=\sqrt{3+\sqrt{(1+2\sqrt{3})^2}}$$
$$=\sqrt{3+1+2\sqrt{3}}$$
$$=\sqrt{(1+\sqrt{3})^2}$$
$$=1+\sqrt3$$

Answer (score 2):

By one line:$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}} =\sqrt{3+\sqrt{1+2\cdot2\sqrt3+12}}= \sqrt{3+1+2\sqrt3}=1+\sqrt3$$

Comment: Squaring isn't one-to-one. So you need to be careful.

Comment: @Fly by Night For positive numbers it's one to one. I posted another solution. See now please.

Answer (score 2):

We have $$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}} = 1+\sqrt{3};$$ that is,
$$3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}=4+2\sqrt{3},$$ I.e.,
$$\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}=1+2\sqrt{3},$$ which is
$$13+4\sqrt{3}=13+4\sqrt{3}.$$ Now just work backwards.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sqrt{3+\sqrt{13+4\sqrt{3}}}= \sqrt{3+\sqrt{{(2\sqrt{3}+1)}^2}} = \sqrt{4+ 2\sqrt{3}} = \sqrt{{(\sqrt{3}+1)}^2} = \sqrt{3}+1.$$

Comment: Sorry. I think, I put it so late.